# Should I programmatically turn on Wifi and Bluetooth scanning for better location accuracy?

Tags: android

I am currently making an app that tracks user movements. Basically, it requires the user to move for a given distance in meter. And since the user can move indoor, I need high accuracy badly. I am using `FusedLocationProviderClient` to do my job.

When the app starts, it will check the location settings to see if they are all satisfied. And if they are not, it will prompt a dialog in which allows the user to just only tap `OK` and then all location settings will be right set.

I have to use `LocationSettingsRequest.Builder` and `ResolvableApiException` class to do that.

The `LocationSettingsRequest.Builder` class gets a `LocationRequest` object as an input and then checks if the location settings in the device are satisfied with the given `LocationRequest` object. Doing so will throw a `ResolvableApiException` object if the location settings of the device are not satisfied. And that `ResolvableApiException` object can prompt a dialog allowing the user to make these settings right. More details at [Change location settings](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html) on developer.android.com

The `LocationSettingsRequest.Builder` need a `LocationRequest` as an input, so this is my `LocationRequest`:

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
```

And my code in my MainActivity to check the location settings:

```
public void checkLocationSettings(){
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
    task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
            // do works
        }
    });
    task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            try {
                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, 1);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 1:
            if(resultCode== RESULT_OK){
                // do works
            }
            else{
                // I will automatically terminate the app in this case
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I am using Samsung Galaxy J7 Pro with Android OS version 8.1.0. In Location setting, there are two options that are `Locating method` and `Improve accuracy`. `Locating method` has 3 options that are `High accuracy`, `Battery saving` and `Phone only`. `Improve accuracy` has 2 options that are `Wi-Fi scanning` and `Bluetooth scanning`.

I tried turning off the device Location, turning off all 2 options in `Improve accuracy` and I set `Locating method` to `Phone only`. Then I opened my app, there was a dialog like this appeared:
[image]

Forget about the situation when the user click `NO THANKS`. When the user click `OK`, I can see the Location service has been activated. The `Locating method` also be set to `High accuracy`. But there is no changes inside `Improve accuracy` options.

This makes me wonder. I wonder if `Improve accuracy` becomes useless when `Locating method` is being `High accuracy`. Or it is not useless at all and I have to programmatically turn them on too.

I'm sorry I can't post all of my code because it's quite complex and redundant for my problem. But if you want, I can create a whole new project to demonstrate the problem. And I don't know if this is a good place to ask something like this too. If it's not, could you show me one? I appreciate any idea or solution.

EDIT: So I have created a new simple project to demonstrate this problem. You can check it [here](https://github.com/daophilac/locationdetector).

Comment: Use GitHub and share ur code. Now, **why Google offers manage options?** Not all the phones have the same hardware and specs. Some will use *Improve accuracy* and *High accuracy* to improve their services others don't provide that feature and the Android OS will ignore it and u will not find any substantial improvement. I recommend u to check [`isLocationEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isLocationEnabled()) method and [MODE_CHANGED_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#MODE_CHANGED_ACTION)

Comment: @Teocci Thank you. Checking location settings status while the app is running is a thing I have to deal with too. Btw, I have just created the demo project, you can clone it, build and immediately run on your phone. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

As per scanning settings description, wifi and bluetooth scanning can work even when wifi and bluetooth are turned off by the user. So manually switching on bluetooth/wifi is not necessary.

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient), setting `builder.setNeedBle(true);` should prompt the user to enable bluetooth scanning if the bluetooth is disabled by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `ResolvableApiException` can actually turn on *Wi-Fi scanning* inside *Improve accuracy* option. But only when the Wifi is not turned on. In that case, the dialog will look like this:
[image]

And when the user click *OK*, it does turn on *Wi-Fi scanning* in *Improve accuracy* option. Note that it doesn't turn on Wifi like you will normally do to surf the net or something like that. It just turns on the feature called *Wi-Fi scanning*

As of the *Bluetooth scanning* feature, I don't know why `ResolvableApiException` doesn't turn it on. But since it does deal with the *Wi-Fi scanning*, I assume that the `ResolvableApiException` is smart enough to decide what it has to do. So, I think I don't need to worry about the accuracy anymore.